# How to add Azure Active Directory role via Graph API or PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an multi-tenant web application for different Azure accounts. I want to add a new custom directory role via PowerShell or Graph API so that I can automate things. I've walked through the reference for the Graph API but there was no any way to do this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog#directory-role-operations

It is possible with PowerShell?

I also want create a new Azure Active Directory programmatically, if possible.

Comment: If there are features you'd like which are missing, remember you can always request/vote for them at [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory). (For example, there's already [a request for custom roles](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/7860354-create-user-roles-in-azure-portal), you can add your vote.)

Answer (score 1):

Custom directory roles are not yet supported in Azure AD, only built-in roles.

Programmatically creating a new Azure AD directory is not supported.

Comment: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/ here in this example they show how to add custom roles.

Comment: Those are app roles, not directory roles. App roles do not grant any permissions on the directory, it is up to the application developer to interpret app roles and enforce the appropriate behavior. Directory roles are predefined in Azure AD and give permissions on directory objects (e.g. create user, change password, etc.). Which of the two are you trying to create?